# Which web service to use as a cache storage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, amazon-s3, amazon-elasticache

I am creating an application as a practice which will scrape a website. I want to cache scraped results using a web service, but I am not sure which one to use.

I have looked into Amazon's Elasticache and S3. 
Elasticache seems like an overkill for this problem, but uses Redis in the background which will reduce my workload (I guess?). 
S3 is not in-memory, but bigger issue for me is that I am not completely sure it is good solution for this kind of problem.

I don't need anything super fancy. I would like something easy to set up, yet efficient if that is possible.

So which one to chose? Are there any better alternatives?

Comment: You can always run your own redis/memcached

Comment: @SergioTulentsev And use S3 as a backup storage? I am aiming for completely web based caching storage

Comment: Ah, I see. In this case, google "memcached as a service", maybe you'll get a few suggestions.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev One more question: is there any free memcached service that can be used outside of Rails?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think that Redis will reduce your work load? Redis is really powerful cache and will save your data really good. Elasticache of AWS can works with redis, should be really easy to setup and you only need control the what you will save there.

Comment: "really easy" is an overstatement. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/GettingStarted.html. It can be much easier.